# identity activation functions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

If I have a neural net with  $L$ hidden layers, and $d^l$ neurons in each layer.
Which functions can be learned if I use the identity activation function?
Is this all the linear functions group?

And which functions can be learned if I limit the $k$ hidden layer to have **at most** $d'$ neurons?
Does it matter and change the previous answer?